# how to use one service to receive notifications for multiple applications?

Tags: web-services, apple-push-notifications

Is there anyone out there who knows if it's possible to use common web service (from same server) to send apple push notification on multiple iOS apps?

I am able to send push notification on my first app(e.g. **ABC** is 1st App) but when I try to use same web service to send push notification on another app(e.g. **XYZ** is 2nd App), it complete the process, device received the notification but it display **ABC app name instead of XYZ App name**.

I don't want to create service for each of my apps. Should I try to register the same service in all my apps, or release the service as a single app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same server and software setup to send push messages to various Apps. Which App the messages go to is determined by the certificates that belong to the bundle id of your specific App. Open the SSL socket with the correct certificates for App ABC and you message App ABC, open the SSL socket with the certificates for App XYZ and you message XYZ.